# How to generate authorization token with cliend id and secret key on MAUI

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, maui

I have a xamarin application and currently migrating that to MAUI. Currently I'm using ADAL for generating the auth token.A mobile number login option is there in my application, after entering the mobile number we are calling an API and passing the number to server.how do I generate auth token for that. Here is my current code to generate token with out any email login. Kindly help me on it.

Here is my code to generate token on Xamarin, we are using this "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory"  nuget for that.

```
  public async Task<string> GenerateAuthenticationTokenAsync(string resourceUrl = "")          
      {     
          var clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(ClientId,ClientSecret);
          var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(TokenAuthority);
          var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceUrl) ? ApiResouceUrl : resourceUrl, clientCredentials); 
         return authResult.Token;}
```

Tried with Microsoft.Identity.client. but it's not working throwing an error ,"Confidential client and managed identity flows are not available on mobile platforms and on Mac.".

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId).
                WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
               .WithAuthority(TokenAuthority).Build();
  string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };

  var authresult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(Scopes).ExecuteAsync();

  string token = authresult.AccessToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the official document about the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` nuget packge.

> This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer
> maintained. Suggested Alternatives: Microsoft.Identity.Client

So you can use the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` package which supports .net 6.0 in the maui project.

And you can check the official document about the [api introduction of the `Microsoft.Identity.Client Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client?view=msal-dotnet-latest) to choose the method about creating token.

Comment: I go through the documents and I found one method for creating access token without login , but which is throwing an error "Confidential client and managed identity flows are not available on mobile platforms and on Mac."

Comment: But this package's official document said it support maui. @Xamarin

Comment: Yes it's working with SSO login ,and I was able to generate user token. But I need to generate access token using client id and secret ,and this one is not working on MAUI

Comment: You can post an issue for this package on the github.